# Dagger2 inject generated class

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dagger-2

I created my own annotation processor library that generate a classes for user. But I got an error while providing those classes using Dagger2.

**Here is the error message:**

```
error: cannot find symbol

private Provider<NonExistentClass> provideUserDataProvider;
                   ^
  symbol:   class NonExistentClass
  location: class DaggerAppComponent
```

Can anyone explain me how to inject generated classes with Dagger2?

Answer (score 1):

By default, the Kotlin Annotation Processor replaces every unknown symbol by `NonExistentClass`.

This may not be suitable for every use cases. You can disable this behavior by setting the Kapt `correctErrorTypes` option to true.

See : http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kapt.html#non-existent-type-correction

It should fix your problem.